# Class TranslatableServiceProvider not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Использую Laravel 5.2.
Пытаюсь добавить пакет в `composer.json` этой командой:

```
 composer require dimsav/laravel-translatable
```

Но получаю следующую ошибку:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Class
>   'Dimsav\Translatable\TranslatableServiceProvider' not found

Что я делаю не так и как мне исправить ошибку?

Comment: Пожалуйста, переведите вопрос на русский. Это как-никак Stack Overflow *на русском*.

Answer (score 1):

Читайте [доку по установке](https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable)

Вы не выполнили вот этот пункт

> Next, add the service provider to app/config/app.php

```
Dimsav\Translatable\TranslatableServiceProvider::class,
```

Comment: Я сделал это, но \Translatable\ вот єто название подсвечивается красным,и пишет, что класс не найден...

Comment: Тогда покажите app.php

Comment: напишите с первым слешом `\Dimsav\Translatable\TranslatableServiceProvider`